# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, mobile-safari, w3c-geolocation

Similar questions have been asked previously, but only relating to iOS 6 not 7. For about a week now I've been trying to get `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to work on two different iPads, one running 6.1.3 another running 7.1.x and the behaviour is identical in both environments. `watchPosition` fires 2-4 times after being called but never runs again. If I go to the home screen and back again it works again 2-4 times in rapid succession and then quits.

Chrome, Safari and as a web app saved to the home screen all work in the same way. I've tried this with and without the `<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">` tag.

I've exhausted combinations of the API to attempt to make this work and the only thing I've come up with is to call `getCurrentPosition` inside of a `setInterval` if the user is running iOS, way less than ideal. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

For anyone who wants to test this:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_watchposition